# JSON parsing with Qt

Tags: c++, mysql, json, qt, parsing

Hei , I have this text in a `JSON`  : 
( without the returns all in one line)

```
    [
        {
            "ERROR":false,
            "USERNAME":"Benutzer",
            "FORMAT":"HUMAN",
            "LATITUDE_MIN":84,
            "LATITUDE_MAX":36,
            "LONGITUDE_MIN":5,
            "LONGITUDE_MAX":20,
            "RECORDS":203
        },
        [
            {
                "MMSI":233434540,
                "TIME":"2014-10-09 06:19:06 GMT",
                "LONGITUDE":8.86037,
                "LATITUDE":54.12666,
                "COG":347,
                "SOG":0,
                "HEADING":236,
                "NAVSTAT":0,
                "IMO":0,
                "NAME":"HELGOLAND",
                "CALLSIGN":"DK6068",
                "TYPE":90,
                "A":20,
                "B":15,
                "C":4,
                "D":4,
                "DRAUGHT":2,
                "DEST":"BREMERHAVEN",
                "ETA":"00-00 00:00"
            },
            {
                "MMSI":319072300,
                "TIME":"2014-10-09 06:08:53 GMT",
                "LONGITUDE":9.71578,
                "LATITUDE":54.31949,
                "COG":343.6,
                "SOG":0,
                "HEADING":197,
                "NAVSTAT":5,
                "IMO":1012189,
                "NAME":"M.Y. ESTER III",
                "CALLSIGN":"ZGED3",
                "TYPE":37,
                "A":31,
                "B":35,
                "C":7,
                "D":6,
                "DRAUGHT":3.5,
                "DEST":"SCHACT AUDORF",
                "ETA":"09-16 08:00"
            }

    // many more lines but the Json IS VALID.

    ]
   ]
```

I would parse it and put that in a `MYSQL` table. 
Not all, only name and `MMSI` first. 
But this don't view anything in my consle because its dont jump in the foreach:

```
bool ok = true;

// my json data is in reply & ok is a boolean
QVariantList result = parser.parse(reply, &ok).toList();

foreach(QVariant record, result) {
    QVariantMap map = record.toMap();
    qDebug() << map.value("NAME");
}
```

What's wrong ? 
When i debug, i only see that it doesn't jump in the foreach.
I use the QJson libary : QJson::Parser parser; But please anyone can tell me what i do wrong?

Comment: Just saw that you need the solution in Qt4. I would suggest you to try [qjson4](https://code.google.com/p/qjson4/) as I have suggested in my answer. I have given a code snippet as well.

Comment: have you found an alternate solution for this problem? If yes, please share it with others.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like you are iterating over top level array, while the data you are looking for is in the nested array, which is effectively the second item of the top level array. So, you need to iterate over items in the inner array.

The following code works for me with your sample JSON:

```
QVariantList result = parser.parse(reply, &ok).toList().at(1).toList();
foreach (const QVariant &item, result) {
    QVariantMap map = item.toMap();
    qDebug() << map["NAME"].toString();
    qDebug() << map["MMSI"].toLongLong();
}
```

Comment: Yes, but i must use Qt 4.

Comment: Then you are already using QJson I guess. Is `ok` `true` after calling `parse()`?

Comment: @thelittlePanda, I've updated my answer with my guess about the problem.

Comment: i alredy use the libary : QJson::Parser parser; Can nobody say me what's wrong with my code ? The Json is okey. I use the QJson libary. but my  problem is that it doen't jump in the foreach.

Comment: yes, that i alredy have tried, but when i use it so , it makes this error : ASSERT failure in QList<T>::at: "index out of range", file /usr/include/QtCore/qlist.h, line 469

Comment: Hm, I've just tried and it works fine with the sample JSON. Check output to `qDebug()` on every stage, so you can see what data is actually in these `QVariant`s.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) 
But it's stange, then when i write it so, it views the same error : ASSERT failure in QList<T>::at: "index out of range", file /usr/include/QtCore/qlist.h, line 469 when i delete the code, it dont views this error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62730/discussion-between-thelittlepanda-and-oleg-shparber).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Qt5 or above, you can make use of the awesome features provided by [QJsonDocument](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qjsondocument.html), [QJsonObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qjsonobject.html) and [QJsonArray](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qjsonarray.html).

I have copied your json into a file named test.txt in my D-drive and the code below works fine.

```
QJsonDocument jsonDoc;
QByteArray temp;
QFile file("D://test.txt");
if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    temp = file.readAll();
}
jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(temp);
QJsonArray jsonArray = jsonDoc.array().at(1).toArray(); //Since you are interested in the json array which is the second item and not the first json object with error
for(int i =0; i < jsonArray.size(); ++i)
{
    QJsonObject jsonObj = jsonArray.at(i).toObject();
    int mmsi = jsonObj.find("MMSI").value().toInt();
    QString name = jsonObj.find("NAME").value().toString();
    qDebug() << mmsi;
    qDebug() << name;
}
```

If you have to stick to Qt4, you can try using the [qjson4](https://code.google.com/p/qjson4/) library which tries to mimic the behavior of the 'QJsonDocument' which is part of Qt5.